# Why is Java buffered stdin/stdout failing in this code?

Tags: java, io, video-processing

I am trying to change gplay's volume level programmatically in a Java app running on ubuntu. The video plays fine; I see gplay's menu; I get my first "Playing" prompt, and I write a "v" for "[v]Volume" but I never see the volume prompt "Set volume." I get all of the data I expect from BufferedReader, but BufferedWriter does not seem to be working. Everything works as expected when I run gplay from the console. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. gplay is a "command-line player which is based on the Gstreamer architecture. Gstreamer is a powerful, versatile framework for creating streaming media applications" from  Freescale Semiconductor.

Thank you.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("gplay");
command.add("demoVideo.mp4");

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File("/home/ubuntu"));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process playVideoProcess = builder.start();

// get the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess
InputStream is = playVideoProcess.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

// get the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess
OutputStream os = playVideoProcess.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

while (true)
{
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        if (debug) logger.log(Level.INFO, "--> " + line);

        if (line.contains("[Playing  ][Vol=01]"))
        {
            bw.write("v");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        else if (line.contains("Set volume"))
        {
            bw.write("10");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        else if (line.contains("[Playing  ][Vol=10]"))
        {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "* Done. CLOSING ALL STREAMS *");
            bw.close();
            osw.close();
            os.close();

            br.close();
            isr.close();
            is.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: turn on debug and add your logfile output to your question

Answer (score 0):

does gplay literally output "[Playing  ][Vol=01]"? Because line.contains does only look at the literal string and does not work for example with regex or other advanced string matching systems. (Because I assume you are using [] to make it optional)

Comment: Here's what the I/O looks like in interactive mode (edited for comment size limitations):

ubuntu@nitrogen:~$ gplay demoVideo.mp4
fsl_player_play()
FSL_PLAYER_01.00_LINUX build
        [v]Volume
        [r]Switch to repeated mode or not
        [x]eXit
  
[Playing  ][Vol=01][00:00:03/00:02:39][fps:34]v
Set volume[0-1.0]:10
[Playing  ][Vol=10][00:00:19/00:02:39][fps:30]r
input repeated mode[0 for no repeated,1 for play list repeated,2 for current file repeated]:2
[Playing  (Current Repeated)][Vol=10][00:00:24/00:02:39][fps:30]FOUND GST_MESSAGE_TAG!